# How do you show a variable(string/int) from PHP file, to an HTML file?

Tags: php, html

ive been trying to google this few times but most of the result i found is echoing an HTML code from an PHP file: instead of .html, i need to change my file to .php file in the first place. but in my case i want to echo a variable from .php file then send it to .html file.

my current code in html is:

```
<p name="first"> </p>
<p name ="second"> </p>
<p name ="third"></p>
```

so as you can see, the code of P in my html is empty. it doesnt have text or message when i try to open it in a web browser.

so in php file, how should i code it? for example i want to echo a "HELLO!"(String) from PHP then pass it to HTML in the `<p name="first"></p>`?

Comment: Think you need to read up a little on ther basics of PHP. If you want to use PHP code, then name the page with a .php extension. A PHP page contains both HTML and PHP code. It is not really any different from a page with a `.html` extension other than if it has a `.php` extension, Apache knows to pass it through the PHP interpreter so that the PHP code can contribute to the building of an HTML page

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn some php-basics. This is an example, how insert a string with php in your html-code. your file-extension must be .php

```
<p name="first"><?php echo "HELLO!"; ?></p>
<p name="second"> </p>
<p name="third"></p>
```

this output is the same, but now you're using a variable:

```
<?php
$variable = "HELLO!";
?>
<p name="first"><?php echo $variable; ?></p>
<p name="second"> </p>
<p name="third"></p>
```

or you can print the whole html-line with php:

```
<?php
$variable = "HELLO!";
echo '<p name="first">' . $variable . '</p>';
echo '<p name="second">HEY</p>';
?>
```